# Solving an inequality with a constraint

Tags: inequality

I have the following inequality:

$|a\frac{e^{-ax}}{(e^{-ax}+1)^2}| \geq 1$

The solution for this can only exist if $|a| \geq 4$. I want to find the range of values for $x$ where the above inequality is true. I think if I can isolate $x$ in this equation, I would have solved it. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to do that. I begin by moving the denominator towards the right.

$a e^{-ax} \geq (e^{-ax}+1)^2$

This leads me to

$\ln a -ax \geq \ln (e^{-ax}+1)^2$

At this stage I am stuck. I can't figure out how to isolate $x$ from the RHS. I have tried other approaches as well - such as expanding the square term before bringing in the log or partially moving out one term from the denomination towards the right - they all leads to an expression where I can't figure out how to isolate $x$

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, we can assume $ a>0$.

Put $$ t=e^{-ax}$$

The inequation becomes
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{(1+t)^2}\ge \frac 1a$$

but

$$f'(t)=\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t)^4}$$
So
$$\max f(t)=f(1)=\frac 14$$

and necessarily,
$$\frac 1a\le \frac 14$$
or
$$a\ge 4$$

You need to solve the inequation above for $ t $ and then for $ x$.

We have
$$t^2+(2-a)t+1\le 0$$

then

$$t\in[\frac{a-2-\sqrt{a(a-4)}}{2},\frac{a-2+\sqrt{a(a-4)}}{2}]\cap (0,+\infty)$$

Comment: No, you dont answer the question

Comment: @NN2 If we solve for t, we will solve for x.

Comment: Of course it’s not difficult to solve for t (and/or) for x. But you didn’t do both. So, you didn’t answer the question

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you had the derivative of f(t)?

Comment: To find its maximum.

Comment: Why do you need the maximum?

Comment: To find the necessay condition on $a$ which is $ a\ge 4$.

Comment: You don’t need to calculate the derivative of f(t). It suffices to calculate the delta of the inequality and the necessary condition is delta must be not negative

Comment: @NN2 Yes, you are right, but it is an other approach. Thanks.

Comment: What is delta of the inequality?

Comment: $\Delta=(2-a)^2-4=a(a-4)$

Comment: Could you please point to me to some resources which teach me how to compute the delta of the inequality? As far as I know, delta refers to difference or change. I am not sure how that applies here and thus this answer does not seem obvious to me.

Comment: @mathnewbie I meant the delta of $t^2 + (2-a)t+1 = 0$! I refer this to the inequality of hamam